# Ubuntu: Inspect web elements w/ Chrome Dev Tools on Samsung Galaxy s9

Tags: android, debugging, web-applications, google-chrome-devtools, samsung-mobile

After following all of these steps I have yet to successfully inspect / debug my web app using chrome dev tools and my samsung s9 Chrome browser:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=en

My device is not showing up in the list of remote devices in Chrome on my desktop, and virtually all of the posts exploring this process are not on Linux.

Comment: What are you seeing in the **Remote Devices** tab? Nothing?

Comment: Yep, I am seeing nothing. It says near the bottom: "No devices detected. Read remote debugging documentation for more information." It then links to the link seen in my question. Now could it be the port forwarding? If I am running a build of my webapp on localhost:3333, would I need to forward that port (it currently is forwarded). I access my desktop's localhost:3333 on my Galaxy, from going to my desktop's IP Address and then the same port [ip.address]:3333 in my mobile's chrome app. I can browse the webapp from my phone no problem, just can't seem to debug it as my device is not listed.

Comment: @KayceBasques any advancements on this issue?